# How to deploy a contract to api-kylin.eosasia.one testnet

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, testnet

I have written a helloworld contract and got compiled that successfully
thomsonim123 is my kylin testnet account with some EOS when I want to deploy the contracct to the testnet I get few errors.

Command to deploy
`cleos -u https://api-kylin.eosasia.one set contract thomsonim123 /home/savi/Documents/thomson/eos/contract/hello`

Error

```
Publishing contract...
Error 3120006: No available wallet
Ensure that you have created a wallet and have it open
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not very familiar with eosio i suggest to read https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs this documentation.